# Restaurar pasta excluida Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Olá gostaria de saber se tem algum jeito de restaurar uma pasta deletada dentro do Android Studio, no Eclipse existe essa a opção "Restore from Local History" porém não sei se é possível fazer o mesmo com o Android Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acabei dando uma fuçada na barra de menu e acabei encontrando a solução.

Na barra de menu do Android Studio vá em **View > Recent Changes** e irá ter a opção **"Revert"**